# How to load view file in core functions in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am trying to load view file in application/core/MY_Controller.php but its giving as follows.

```
Message: Undefined property: Edustaticlanding::$load

Filename: core/MY_Controller.php
```

Function is as follows in MY_Controller.php

```
function menu(){
    $arrr = array();
    return $arrdata['menu'] = $this->load->view('menu',$arrr,true);
}
```

And am calling this function in controller(Edustaticlanding.php) as follows.

```
function __construct(){
    $this->menucontent = $this->menu();
    print_r($this->menucontent); die;
}
```

Pls correct me.. where its going wrong.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On  application/core/MY_Controller.php

Add public `$data = array()` like below

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['menu'] = $this->menu();
    }

    public function menu(){
        return $this->load->view('menu', NULL, TRUE);
    }
}
```

On the controller then once add public $data = array(); you can access the menu on view

> You have to use `$this->data` now on controller

```
<?php

class Example extends MY_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    public function index() {

        $this->data['title'] = 'Welcome to Codeigniter';

        $this->load->view('example', $this->data);

    }
}
```

On the example view now you can echo

```
<?php echo $menu;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `extends CI_Controller` to your core controller like following codes:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below mentioned solution. You need to call parent constructor first. So it will load all basic configurations.

First extent `CI_Controller` class and call parent constructor like describe below

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct{
       parent::__construct();
   }

}
```

Please let me if it not works.

Comment: am doing this already..i got sol.. i forgot to add parent::__construct() in               
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->menucontent = $this->menu();
    print_r($this->menucontent); die;
}